# Mutating Columns with paste0

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to dynamically name columns. I need to duplicate variables with new names. Why isn't the new_sepal_length_2 variable the same as new_sepal_length? How can I fix this?

```
new_var = 'Sepal.Length'
iris %>% mutate(new_sepal_length = Sepal.Length,
new_sepal_length_2 = noquote(paste0(new_var)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert it to symbol (`sym`) and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
iris %>%
     mutate(new_sepal_length = str_c(!!rlang::sym(new_var), collapse=", "))
```

Or another option is to make use of `mutate_at` which can take strings in `vars`

```
iris %>%
   mutate_at(vars(new_var), list(new= ~ str_c(., collapse=", ")))
```

Or use `paste`

```
iris %>%
   mutate(new_sepal_length = paste(!!rlang::sym(new_var), collapse = ", "))
```

`paste0` or `paste` by itself only converts to `character` class.  Perhaps, we may need to use the arguments in `paste`